# Retrieve Values form Jquery Ajax Json in Laravel 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to retrieve data from an Jquery Plugin which uses Ajax and Json in Laravel 4

The Plugin part is in the view customer.blade.php:

```
<script>
var $container = $("#dataTable");
var $console = $("#example1console");

  var data = {{ $content }};
  $("#dataTable").handsontable({
    data: data,
    startRows: 6,
    startCols: 8,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: [{{ $title }}]
  });

var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');

$container.parent().find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
    //alert('we are trying to save');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/",
    data: {"data": 'demo data'}, //handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (res) { console.log(res); alert(res); }
   /* error: function () {
      $console.text('Save error. POST method is not allowed on GitHub Pages. Run this example on your own server to see the success message.');
    }*/
  });
});
</script>
```

in Routes.php i have:

```
// here i wanna send json data to plugin and render the view 
Route::get('/', 'CustomerController@getIndex');
// here i wanna retrieve the  json-data from the plugin and save it later in db
Route::post('/', 'CustomerController@postSave');
```

in Controller i have:

```
public function getIndex() {
    //$cust = Customer::get()->toJson();
    //$cust = InformationDB::select('Column_Name')->where('table_name', '7_0 - CRONUS (ai-Patches) AG$Customer')->get()->toJson();

    // Get Columns
    $cust = Customer::select('Name', 'City')->get()->toJson();
    // Get Columns Title
    $getTitle = Customer::select('Name', 'City')->first()->toJson();
    $title = implode(', ',array_keys(json_decode($getTitle, true)));
    $title4js = "'" . str_replace(",", "','", $title) . "'";
    // Render View
    return View::make('customer/customer', array('content' => $cust, 'title' => $title4js));
}

public function postSave() {
    $t = Input::all(); 
    return $t;
}
```

Maybe someone knows what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What your getting in console output?

Comment: nothing, i even can see chromedevtool->network a new connection to localhost, when i' click on the save button and in the header-information my json data i which i would like to save..

Comment: Use this ``$.ajax({
            url: "/laranav/public/",
            data: {"data": 'demo data'}, //returns all cells' data
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (res) {
              console.log(res);
              alert(res);
            }
       });`` and now what you are getting? any error?

Comment: from controller use this ``public function postSave() {
    $t = Input::all();
    return $t;
}``

Comment: sadly not everything is like before, just nothing happens, only the connection apperas on every klick on save...

Comment: did you got the alert?

Comment: no, i did not get an alert or log.. just nothing..

Comment: Try my code and tell me what you are getting?

Comment: i have you're code active running.. but nothing happens..

Comment: Now what is the output in console? i mean you seen some post url or error?

Comment: nothing is in the console output.. no error, no message. yes like ever before i still ever get a new connection when i klick onsave, with you're data:demo data, but only thourg chromedevtools->network->header

Comment: where you are calling the ajax? can you update the js part in question?

Comment: Ok, did you got ``alert('we are trying to save');`` this alert working after commenting out?

Comment: yes, this one works -> then the new connection appears but nothing more..

Comment: what is the connection url?

Comment: Now try ``Route::post('/', function()
{
 $t = Input::all();
    return $t;
});`` instead of ``Route::post('/', 'CustomerController@postSave');``

Comment: 127.0.0.1 / POST / 200 OK

Comment: still the same... but i can have url in js / or /laranav/public both gives a 200 ok, but doenst works either.. just something that also confuses me..

Comment: So look your url, it's ``127.0.0.1 /`` So in js you need to add correct url like ``/laranav/`` or ``/laranav/public/``

Comment: then i get 2 connections -> GET 200 OK and after that -> POST 301 moved permanently

Comment: please comment full url for both action here.

Comment: http://snag.gy/b9vxq.jpg screenshot of them, after i clicked once on save, thanks for trying to help, so long !!!

Comment: You are not added ``/`` after your post url, so your post url should be ``/laranav/public/``

Comment: now i have in console "Object {data: "demo data"} " .. but nothing in my laravel..

Comment: Now you got the input values in console.. you can use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ajax post` request, Instead of

```
url: "/",
```

You have to use,

```
url: "/laranav/public/",
```

The `laranav` will be your project directory.

Comment: @user2834172 You are welcome, you can ask if you have any other doubts.

Comment: should i make a new question? from the retrieved json i wanna save it now in the db  `public function postSave() {
  //$t = Input::all();
  $t = Input::get('Name');
  $c = Customer::find('DKT000142');
  $c->Name = $t;
  $c->save();
  //return $t;
 }` gives status error 500

Comment: make a new question and you should explain the error string you got when expanding the request url in console and explain table field names.